# SQL Server : combine multiple records into one field

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have created the following SQL script:

```
SELECT 
    E.ID,  
    abc = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + E2.ExclusionID
                 FROM Exclusion E2
                 WHERE E.ID = E2.ID 
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') 
FROM
    Exclusion E 
GROUP BY 
    E.ContractMovementID
```

It combines all exclusion records for the ID into one record and displays as below:

```
ID     ExclusionID
-------------------
1      123
2      2345
3      4567
```

However, I would like it to display as:

```
ID     ExclusionID
-------------------    
1      1 2 3
2      23 45
3      45 67
```

So that the columns are separated with space, however, I cannot seem to get it to put a space between them. Can anyone help me with this? (I hope this makes sense)

Thanks

Jessica

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, because the exclusion.id was an INT data type i had to convert it into a varchar to be able to add a seperator.

```
SELECT 
    E.ID,  
    abc = STUFF((SELECT CAST(E2.ExclusionID AS VARCHAR) + ','
                 FROM Exclusion E2
                 WHERE E.ID = E2.ID 
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')  FROM
    Exclusion E  GROUP BY 
    E.ContractMovementID
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
    E.ID,  
    abc = STUFF((SELECT '  ' + E2.ExclusionID
                 FROM Exclusion E2
                 WHERE E.ID = E2.ID 
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    Exclusion E 
GROUP BY 
    E.ContractMovementID
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Still does not seem to work and also putting 1,1 seems to take the remove the first digit.

Comment: @JessicaNutt what about having 2 spaces in the `SELECT`?

Comment: I did also try that still nothing, but i have found a solution i need to but cast around the e2.exlcusionID and change it to a varchar then i can put ',' next to it